# Remove commas from a csv column using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have the following code which removes all the commas in my csv file but there is an issue:

I only want to remove commas on Column P and and the remaining data should be untouched. Currently it appends data underneath the csv data.

```
$inform = Get-Content C:\Users\bmd\Desktop\report.csv
$inform.ToString()
$y=$inform -replace ',' -replace ''
$y  | Out-file C:\Users\bmd\Desktop\report.csv -Append
```

Comment: Does your CSV use the comma as the column separator? Does your csv have a header row?

Comment: What type of information is in column P? It would be helpful for you to provide this. I would use import-csv rather than get-content if the csv isn't comma delimited.

Comment: `-Append` adds the output to the end of an existing file. I think what you are looking for is a way to first manipulate the content of the CSV then write back that (entire) content to the same file?

Comment: Hi,yes my csv has headers.. Basically the columns A through O in my csv file are all separate columns and the data is structured.. it’s only the data in column P which is comma delimited with quotes which I would like to replace comma with nothing. Overall goal is to just replace comma in column p with nothing and save the csv as it is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` is usually going to be easier than trying to manipulate strings in a CSV. With no sample of the CSV file, we can only make assumptions. Assuming it contains true and qualified as needed CSV data, you can try the following:

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\bmd\Desktop\report.csv
foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $row.UNSTRUCTURED_VARS = $row.UNSTRUCTURED_VARS -replace ','
}
$csv | Export-Csv C:\Users\bmd\Desktop\report.csv -NoType
```

---

Note that if you are on PowerShell Core or PowerShell 7, you can simply use `Export-Csv` with `-UseQuotes AsNeeded` and only the required fields will be qualified.

Comment: Hi @AdminOfThingsI Can you please check if the code below is right as it does nothing.

Comment: Then you should post a sample of your CSV file so we don't have to guess. You also need to remove `-Header $headers` if your file has headers.

Comment: You can download the file here. Colum P I don't need commas: https://esquirebank.box.com/s/y187a3oqz4u0fhpz3mq1sdit02pepusk

Comment: I made a new edit that will exclusively use the `*-Csv` commands.